# R: Is there a way to find partial string matches with the same first element of both the string columns in two different dfs?

Tags: r, string, string-matching

I have two string columns in two different dataframes df1 and df2 -> `df1$name` and `df2$name`. df1 has more than 10000 rows, while df2 has around 200+ rows. For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("Peter P", "Jim Gordon",  "Bruce Wayne", "Tony Stark","Mony Blake" ))

df2<- data.frame(name = c( "Jeter P", "Bruce Wayne", "Mony Blake" ))
```

NOTE: the dfs are much larger than these.

I used merge function first. It matched the common rows first but for "Jeter P" it didn't. 
Then I used a partial matching function `amatch` from Stringdist library with `method = "lv"`. It matched Peter P to Jeter P, two different individuals. I know that amatch takes the changes in positions and alphabets etc, but i want the function to search the the df while keeping the first element of the string same while matching the string.

Basically when I use partial string matching for `Jeter P` in `df2$name` it will only consider rows from `df1$name` where the string starts with J as potential partial matches. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RonakShah's deleted answer could be fixed by extracting the `match_fun` from `stringdist_join`, modifying it to require a first letter match, and using it in `fuzzy_inner_join`.

Comment: Can you please expand on it?

Comment: I did.  Could you please point out the problems with the answer in a comment on it, or accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RonakShah posted a version of this earlier today, but then deleted it since his solution didn't quite match the requirements.

The idea is to use the `fuzzyjoin` package, which has a lot of functions to do fuzzy matching between two datasets.  None of them exactly match the requirements of this question, but here's a longer answer that should do it.

The `stringdist_inner_join` function does a regular fuzzy match.  It works by constructing a complicated function to use in `fuzzy_join`.
It doesn't export that function; but you can make your own function (I'm calling it `stringdist_match`) that just creates the function and exports it.  Then combine that with one that compares first letters, and use the compbined function (`custom_match`) in `fuzzy_join`.  Here's some code.  Most of the `stringdist_match` function is copied from the `fuzzyjoin` package.

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)

stringdist_match <- function(max_dist = 2,
                            method = c("osa", "lv", "dl", "hamming", "lcs", "qgram",
                                       "cosine", "jaccard", "jw", "soundex"),
                            mode = "inner",
                            ignore_case = FALSE,
                            distance_col = NULL, ...) {
  # It's a good idea to force evaluation of all the arguments
  # in case they get changed between when we call this function and 
  # when we use the function it returns.

  force(max_dist)
  force(mode)
  force(ignore_case)
  force(distance_col)
  forceotherargs <- list(...)

  method <- match.arg(method)

  if (method == "soundex") {
    # soundex always returns 0 or 1, so any other max_dist would
    # lead either to always matching or never matching
    max_dist <- .5
  }

  function(v1, v2) {
    if (ignore_case) {
      v1 <- stringr::str_to_lower(v1)
      v2 <- stringr::str_to_lower(v2)
    }

    # shortcut for Levenshtein-like methods: if the difference in
    # string length is greater than the maximum string distance, the
    # edit distance must be at least that large

    # length is much faster to compute than string distance
    if (method %in% c("osa", "lv", "dl")) {
      length_diff <- abs(stringr::str_length(v1) - stringr::str_length(v2))
      include <- length_diff <= max_dist

      dists <- rep(NA, length(v1))

      dists[include] <- stringdist::stringdist(v1[include], v2[include], method = method, ...)
    } else {
      # have to compute them all
      dists <- stringdist::stringdist(v1, v2, method = method, ...)
    }
    ret <- tibble::tibble(include = (dists <= max_dist))
    if (!is.null(distance_col)) {
      ret[[distance_col]] <- dists
    }
    ret
  }
}

# Now the example.  First, create a matching function that
# just does the fuzzy part.
fuzzy_match <- stringdist_match()

# Next create a matching function that just compares first letters.
first_letter_match <- function(col1, col2) 
  sub("(^.).*", "\\1", col1) == sub("(^.).*", "\\1", col2)

# Now create one that requires both to match.
custom_match <- function(col1, col2) 
  first_letter_match(col1, col2) & fuzzy_match(col1, col2)

# Now run the example

df1 <- data.frame(name = c("Peter P", "Jim Gordon",  "Bruce Wayne", "Tony Stark","Mony Blake" ))

df2<- data.frame(name = c( "Jeter P", "Bruce Wayne", "Mony Blake" ))

fuzzy_inner_join(df1, df2, by = "name", match_fun = custom_match)
#>        name.x      name.y
#> 1 Bruce Wayne Bruce Wayne
#> 2  Mony Blake  Mony Blake
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

For documentation for all the arguments to `stringdist_match`, see `?fuzzyjoin::stringdist_join`.